# Change CSS by passing data between siblings

Tags: reactjs

I have two child components. The first child is an image and the second child is a search input. When I type something in the input field, I want the image to hide itself. The passing of data from the second child to the parent goes well. But the first child still appears...

```
Parent: 
class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          displayValue: 'block'
        };
      }

  hideImage = () => () => {
    alert('You pressed a key, now the apple should be gone')
    this.setState ({
      displayValue: 'none'
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Image />
      <Search hideImage={this.hideImage()}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));

First Child:
export default class Image extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <img style={{display : this.props.displayValue}} src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTAxoq2YSBjoS0Lo3-zfqghoyNzZ9jHxoOc5xuFBoopMtKP6n4B"></img>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

Second Child: 
export default class Search extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input onInput={this.props.hideImage} placeholder="Search someting"></input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing the `displayValue` prop to the `Image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the displayValue state into your Image component as a prop. Also you have to pass the hideImage function without initializing it using the two brackets. The below code should work for you.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          displayValue: 'block'
        };
      }

  hideImage = () => () => {
    alert('You pressed a key, now the apple should be gone')
    this.setState ({
      displayValue: 'none'
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Image displayValue={this.state.displayValue}/>
      <Search hideImage={this.hideImage}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just had a couple of typos.

```
class Image extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <img
              style={{ display: this.props.displayValue }}
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTAxoq2YSBjoS0Lo3-zfqghoyNzZ9jHxoOc5xuFBoopMtKP6n4B"
              alt="altprop"
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
}

// Second Child:
class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onInput={this.props.hideImage} placeholder="Search someting" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      displayValue: "block"
    };

  }

  hideImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You pressed a key, now the apple should be gone");
    this.setState({
      displayValue: "none"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image displayValue={this.state.displayValue}/>
        <Search hideImage={this.hideImage.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The passing data to parent and down to siblings gets a me little confused. But it works now, thanks to all of your suggestions. Just a question, how come you use bind(this) ?

Answer (score 0):

Call your Image component like this

```
<Image displayValue={this.state.displayValue} />
```

It should then already work, but here is a shorter way to write your code.

```
// First Child:
const Image = ({displayValue}) => <div>
  <img alt='' style={{display : displayValue}} src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTAxoq2YSBjoS0Lo3-zfqghoyNzZ9jHxoOc5xuFBoopMtKP6n4B"></img>
</div>
```